# pandas: fill missing data in data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have the following `pandas` data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [1, 14, 30]
data = dict(quantities=[1, 4, 9], e_quantities=[1, 2, 3])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=data.keys(), index=timestamps)
```

which looks like this:

```
    quantities  e_quantities
1            1             1
14           4             2
30           9             3
```

However, the `timestamps` should run from 1 to 52:

```
index = pd.RangeIndex(1, 53)
```

The following line provides the `timestamps` that are missing:

```
series_fill = pd.Series(np.nan, index=index.difference(df.index)).sort_index()
```

**How can I get the `quantities` and `e_quantities` columns to have NaN values at these missing timestamps?**

I've tried:

```
df = pd.concat([df, series_fill]).sort_index()
```

but it adds another column (`0`) and swaps the order of the original data frame:

```
     0  e_quantities  quantities
1  NaN           1.0         1.0
2  NaN           NaN         NaN
3  NaN           NaN         NaN
```

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `reindex`

```
df=df.reindex(index)
```